# find special order n length combinations of two n length arrays

Tags: algorithm

Given two N length arrays, find the N length combinations of those arrays giving precedence to the elements of the B array.

For example, given the input of arrays `A: [1,2,3]` and `B: [4,5,6]`
`Fun(A,B)` could yield:

`[4, 5, 6] -> contains 3 from the B array
[4, 5, 3] -> contains 2 from the B array
[4, 2, 6] -> contains 2 from the B array
[1, 5, 6] -> contains 2 from the B array
[4, 2, 3] -> contains 1 from the B array 
[1, 5, 3] -> contains 1 from the B array
[1, 2, 6] -> contains 1 from the B array`

What is most important, is that the most elements in the B array appear first when yielding combinations.

P.S. I would prefer a linear runtime solution of K where K is the number of combinations that can be created (`2^N`).

Comment: step 1: use general algorithm to generate combinations of all elements
step 2: sort according to occurance of elements in B

Comment: Yes, I added an edit to prefer linear runtime

Comment: linear runtime? As a function of what?

Comment: also, should all the elements be unique? What happens when an element occurs in both arrays?

Comment: We can assume that all the elements are unique, yes. Thanks for your interest. :)

Comment: Linear to what? Even when you take only one element from B and rest from A, total number of combinations become N*(N-1) which is greater than linear.

Comment: this is what I mean by linear runtime complexity:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean now. Linear runtime as a function of the number of combinations that are returned (2^N). Sorry for the confusion. The combinations are trivial, producing the combinations presorted is challenging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `2 ** N` combinations (or `2 ** N - 1` of you ignore a combination having all elements from `A`), so just listing them has a run time far from linear of `N`.

To generate them notice that each combination corresponds to an `N`-bit number, with `0` meaning "take an element from `A`", and `1` meaning "take an element from `B`". So, generate all `N`-bit numbers, and sort them according to the popcount.

It is possible to generate them directly in a correct order, with the exponential space complexity penalty.

Comment: that's really close, but there is a bug with that solution:
I have coded it up here:
https://gist.github.com/pnikonowicz/f38ec30948ff21a798cb363cd7fb68e7

Comment: @paul: what is the bug?

Comment: the 4th element returned from this solution results with only 1 item from the B array instead of 2 items. It's because of the recursive nature of the algorithm. The gist that I have linked shows a more detailed analysis of what this algorithm will return.

Comment: Sorting them after finding the combinations won't work for me. The number of combinations is too large, and I probably will only care about the first 3-100 combinations.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be constructed as follows:

1. Start with all combinations of N elements taken from B.
2. Then take all combinations of N-1 elements taken from B and combine
   them with an element of A.
3. Then take all combinations of N-1 elements taken from B and combine them with all combinations of 2 elements taken from A.
4. ...

You can search the web for efficient implementations of combinatorics. If needed i can provide a simple one.